# How can I get new random values with each blank in ReplaceAll?

Tags: replacement, random, rule

Is there any way to get different values for different blanks with `ReplaceAll[]`? For example, I would like to do something like:

```
{_,_,_}/. _Blank -> RandomInteger[{1, 10}]
```

But, the output comes out as all the same random integer for each blank, such as:

```
{4, 4, 4}
```

Is there an efficient way to get an output that is more random, like:

```
{4, 7, 1}
```

,as shown above?

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose something like `Replace[{_, _, _}, _ :> RandomInteger[{1, 10}], {1}]` would do what you ask for, but why not just use `RandomInteger[{1,10}, 3]` instead?

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea - I should have been more specific though, because it wasn't just for {,,}, but also for variable lengths, such as {,}, or even {,{,}} and such

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply change the `Rule ->` to `RuleDelayed :>` to give

```
{_, _, _} /. _Blank :> RandomInteger[{1, 10}]

(*{5, 1, 3}*)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just for variety:  you can also temporarily redefine `Blank` as `RandomInteger[{1,10}]&` using  [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html):

```
Block[{Blank = RandomInteger[{1, 10}] &}, {_, _, x, y, _, z}]
```

> {5, 7, x, y, 5, z}

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it!